# Adding multiple attributes to Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, show-hide

I'm currently working on a set of tables and i've gotten them to expand and contract at the click of a button. I'm having problems however to create a button that expands all the tables at the same time. Please see my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>   <!--this first part is easy to implement-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggler").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.vis'+$(this).attr('vistoggle')).toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="toggler" vistoggle="1">Expand all</a> <!--vistoggle needs to have values 1 and 2 in it-->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>safeaef</td>
        <td>asdfaef</td>
        <td>asfead</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="toggler" vistoggle="1">Expand</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="vis1" style="display:none">
        <td>asdfae</td>
        <td>zxcvry</td>
        <td>rteyertr</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='vis1' style='display:none'>
        <td>tsersg</td>
        <td>sdgfs</td>
        <td>wregssdf</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="vis1" style="display:none">
        <td>sdfgrs</td>
        <td>sgdfgsr</td>
        <td>Cewret</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>cfasdfas</td>
        <td>1adfaed</td>
        <td>asdfasdfea</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="toggler" vistoggle="2">Expand</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="vis2" style="display:none">
        <td>asdfaefas</td>
        <td>1asdf</td>
        <td>Cisdfae</td>
        <td>22fasdew</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="vis2" style="display:none">
        <td>asdfaef</td>
        <td>1sefa0</td>
        <td>Ciasdf 2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try building a selector like this:
    $('tr[class^="vis"]')
it would select all elements, which class attributes begins with 'vis'.

But from what I see you want the first row to always stay visible, so I would propose to simply separate the table header and it's body like this:

```
<table>
    <thead><tr>...</tr></thead>
    <tbody id="table-one" class="vis">
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <thead><tr>...</tr></thead>
    <tbody id="table-two" class="vis">
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and then you could use a simple:

```
$('tbody.vis').toggle();
```

to toggle all the tables, and for toggle`ing just one of them you can use:

```
$('tbody#tbody-one').toggle();
```

which is probably much better idea for performance reasons (ID is found much faster than classes).
The ID attribute of TBODY can be stored just like you store it right now (in a button's attribute).

Fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/SL4UZ/3/

### Edit

To make your HTML valid, you should use data-attributes or bind your events using javascript instead of simply adding customs attributes inside your `button` tags. For example:

```
<button data-toggle-id="tbody-one">Toggle</button>
```

I updated my fiddle.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted however I noticed a problem. When Toggling all, closed ones are opened and open ones are closed. That means if the user has one open, then it gets closed.

Comment: That's exactly what `jQuery.toggle()` does :) if you want it to behave differently, you need to use `show()` and `hide()` (or fadeIn/fadeOut etc.) functions instead of `toggle()`, and surround them with `if` statements to control the behavior.

Comment: Yep. that's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the attr that needs to be toggled and if it matches all open 1 and 2, this works if your table is not dynamic

```
<a href="#" class="toggler" vistoggle="all">Expand all</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggler").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).attr('vistoggle') == "all"){
             $('.vis1').toggle();  
             $('.vis2').toggle();     
        }else{
            $('.vis'+$(this).attr('vistoggle')).toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6hpbq/

Answer (score 0):

Separate your classes eg `vis1` becomes `vis one` (two classes) Then do a conditional check on the value of the data attribute. If its set to `all`, toggle all elements with the class `vis`, else toggle the specific ones:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggler").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var vistog = $(this).attr('vistoggle');
        if(vistog == 'all'){
             $('.vis').toggle();
        }else{
            $('.vis.' + vistog).toggle();
        }

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="toggler" vistoggle="all">Expand all</a> <!--vistoggle set to all -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>safeaef</td>
        <td>asdfaef</td>
        <td>asfead</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="toggler" vistoggle="one">Expand</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="vis one" style="display:none">
        <td>asdfae</td>
        <td>zxcvry</td>
        <td>rteyertr</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='vis one' style='display:none'>
        <td>tsersg</td>
        <td>sdgfs</td>
        <td>wregssdf</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="vis one" style="display:none">
        <td>sdfgrs</td>
        <td>sgdfgsr</td>
        <td>Cewret</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>cfasdfas</td>
        <td>1adfaed</td>
        <td>asdfasdfea</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="toggler" vistoggle="two">Expand</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="vis two" style="display:none">
        <td>asdfaefas</td>
        <td>1asdf</td>
        <td>Cisdfae</td>
        <td>22fasdew</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="vis two" style="display:none">
        <td>asdfaef</td>
        <td>1sefa0</td>
        <td>Ciasdf 2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```